# For $p$ prime, show that $\Phi_{p^n}(x) = 1 + x^{p^{n-1}} + x^{2p^{n-2}} + \dots +x^{(p-1)^{p^n-1}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

Well I attempted to try this but I failed to solve it: So $$\Phi_{p^{n}}(x)= \frac{x^{p^{n}} - 1}{\Phi_{1}(x) \Phi_{p^{2}}(x) \dots \Phi_{p^{n-1}}(x)}$$

Now I'm just stuck here. I saw a result somewhere on the net that said $\Phi_{p^n}(x) = \Phi_p(x^{p^{n-1}})$. I would just use that, but I don't see why that result is true or know how to show that's true.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

See that $\Phi_{p^r}(X)\neq \Phi_{p}(X^{p^r-1})$ but $\Phi_{p^r}(X)= \Phi_{p}(X^{p^{r-1}})$

See that $$\Phi_{p^r}(X)=\frac{X^{p^r}-1}{\Phi_1(X)\Phi_p(X)\cdots\Phi_{p^{r-1}}(X)}=\frac{\left(X^{p^{r-1}}\right)^p-1}{X^{p^{r-1}}-1}=\Phi_p(X^{p^{r-1}})$$

Can you now apply this to your question?

Comment: What is $\Phi_p(X)$??? I am not expecting you to say $X^{p-1}+\cdots+1$

Comment: That's just: $\frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1}$

Comment: For similar reasons, $\Phi_1(X)\Phi_p(X)\cdots\Phi_{p^{r-1}}(X)=X^{p^{r-1}}-1$

Comment: Hm, is there a reason why they're equal? I just can't see it. I'm not saying you're wrong, but I just don't get why they're equal.

Comment: there is a reason... that is how we define cyclotomic polynomial...

Answer (score 0):

We know that $x^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x)$. Now let $n=p^k$ and use induction on $k$.

Comment: Hm I don't really see how this result really helps here. I tried it by induction and proved that $\Phi_{p^{n+1}}(x) = \Phi_{p^{n+1}}(x)$ but that doesn't really show what I really wanted to show...  Unless I did this completely wrong.

Comment: Note that letting $n=p^k$ gives $(x^{p^k}-1)/(\Phi_{1}(x)\Phi_p(x)\cdots \Phi_{p^{k-1}}(x))=\Phi_{p^k}(x)$

Comment: Ah I wrote it weird. Doing induction, you have the base case $k = 0$ which pretty much follows that $\Phi_p(x)$. Now saying that it's true for all $k$, we want to show that $k+1$ is true. So we have $(x^{p^{k+1}}-1)/(\Phi_{1}(x)\Phi_p(x)\cdots \Phi_{p^{k}}(x)$, now I'm stuck there.